# loop and append json data into UIImage[] in Background Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimage, alamofire

I am currently using Alamofire to Fetch Json data/url-images from a Server.

Everything works fine, and I am able to load all of the url-images from the server into a UIImageView. The user can then swipe from left to right in order to View each image like a Photo Gallery.

Currently, when I fetch the data, I loop through my NSArray, convert each url to become an image, and then Append each Image into a UIImage[].

Looping through the NSArray really slows down my app when it first starts, is there a way to speed this process up? Or a better/faster way to covert the urls into images in the background?

```
var pages = NSArray()

var mutable_pages = NSMutableArray()
var pageImages: [UIImage] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fetchPages()

}

func fetchPages() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.myurl.com/api/pages.json").responseJSON() {
        (_, _, data, _) in

        self.pages = data!.valueForKey("page_url") as NSArray!

        self.mutable_pages = NSMutableArray(array: self.pages)

        ###THIS IS REALLY SLOW, IS THERE A FASTER SOLUTION
        for var i = 0; i < self.mutable_pages.count; i++ {

            ###Construct the imgUrl to get an image URL for the pages
            let urlString: NSString = self.mutable_pages[i] as NSString
            var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
            var imgData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL)!

            ###append each image into UIImage
            self.pageImages.append(UIImage(data: imgData)!)

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If profile your project, I think you will find that `var imgData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL)!` is what is really taking the most time. I also don't think there is any getting around this; fetching images is an intensive task.

Comment: Make sure your image fetching/decoding is done off the main thread. You will also have to design your app to handle any times images are not available because they are still being downloaded

Comment: You can also lazy-fetch your images.  Fetch, say, the first 3 images (image 0, image 1 and image n) and then each time the user swipes, fetch the next image (image 2 if they swipe right, image n-1 if they swipe left)

Comment: @Paulw11 I like your idea, do you have a code sample. I am quite new to iOS.

Comment: Using something like SDWebImage is probably easiest https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out a Solution. I essentially created a custom response serializer using this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial).

This way, instead of receiving the NSData that you then have to convert to a UIImage, you can write a custom response serializer to convert it directly to a UIImage for you.

**CUSTOM RESPONSE**

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
  class func imageResponseSerializer() -> Serializer {
    return { request, response, data in
      if data == nil {
        return (nil, nil)
      }

      let image = UIImage(data: data!, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

      return (image, nil)
  }
}

  func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
    return response(serializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: { (request, response, image, error) in
      completionHandler(request, response, image as? UIImage, error)
    })
  }
}
```

I then used the responseImage found in the Alamofire request inside of **cellForIndexAtIndexPath**

```
var request: Alamofire.Request?

cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).responseImage() {
  (request, _, image, error) in
  if error == nil && image != nil {
    if request.URLString == cell.request?.request.URLString {
      cell.imageView.image = image
    }
  }
}
```